# Identifying word sequence by initial letters

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, acronyms, pardes

I learned from Rav ABY that the Attributes of the month of Av are

Ruling permutation of the letters of the Tetragrammaton HAVAYAH : KEH (really the 8th letter) VAV YOD KEH (ditto), contained in the initial Hebrew letters of Haskeis Ushmo'a Yisrael Hayom... "...take heed and listen, O Israel, this day..." (Deut 27:9).

Given 3 or 4 arbitrary Hebrew letters, how do I find a mapping to a sequence of consecutive words in the Torah (Chumash, 5 books of Moshe) analogous to the example above? Is there a method or a dictionary ?

Comment: Can you write a little introduction to the question, I do not understand it.

Comment: He's basically looking for a "backronym."  For a given set of letters, e.g. mem-tet-alef-yud , find me a phrase in the Torah for which those are the initials (mah tovu ohalecha Yaakov). My advice: download the text from mechon mamre and write a script!

Comment: Thanks Shalom .. I actually have that as plan B :D I was just wondering how non computer people would do it (w/o knowing the text inside out so well that they can do it in the heads ..)

Comment: "in the Torah": the Pentateuch (_Chumash_) specifically?

Comment: Are you asking for software to find Rashei Teivot?